# Соединения lua-скрипта и web-приложения

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, веб-программирование, lua

Мне нужно связать один lua-скрипт и web-приложение таким образом, чтобы первый отправлял информацию последнему, а тот выводил её в реальном времени. Немного подумав, я пришел к выводу, что это можно реализовать с помощью socket'ов (lua - client, web - server). Если моё умозаключение верно, подскажите, с помощью каких языков это можно реализовать, а если нет, посоветуйте правильный алгоритм реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам достаточно написать некую прослойку которая будет дергать ваш скрипт, на любом удобном языке(php, bash, python, lua) и прицепить это к apache(cgi). Или взять любой язык на котором не сложно реализовать веб-сервер + запуск скрипта. Ну а веб приложение на этот сервис должно посылать запрос.